# Metro : HyperlinkButton not responding to click event in a GridViewItem

Tags: xaml, gridview, hyperlink, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Here's my problem, i have a HyperlinkButton inside a GridViewItem which doesn't respond to my click.

I know there is a lot of properties settable corresponding to click management like IsItemClickEnabled, IsHitTestEnabled etc but i can't find the good match which would allow me to click on my hyperlink.

If you have any idea, i'd be glad to hear it.

Thanks

EDIT1 : with only IsHitTestVisible set to True, i can click on my GridViewItems and obviously on my hyperlink inside. But i don't want any reaction from the item itself when i click on the link.

Comment: Have you tried setting SelectionMode to None?

Comment: Yes and the behaviour is as i stated before, the item is clickable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable hover/click effects from GridViewItems/ListViewItems - you need to edit the template.

Check here: [How to disable ListView's Hover and Tile effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790894/how-to-disable-listviews-hover-and-tile-effects/11791615#11791615)

Comment: Yup creating a custom style for the GridViewItem did the trick, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use property `CommandName` in your `LinkButton`

coding handle procedure in `GridView1_RowCommand` , remember check if `(e.CommandName=="Update")`

Comment: I checked the help over and over and there's no Property named CommandName on the HyperlinkButton. Do you have a sample where it does what you say ?